# Vim: Only scroll the current line

Tags: vim, scroll

I would like `vim` to scroll horizontally like `nano` does, by scrolling only the current line, not the whole screen.

I tried playing with `nowrap` and `scrolloff` settings, without success.

Here are some screenshots (with the cursor at the end of a long line) to explain myself.

### Nano:

[image: Nano]

### Vim (wrap):

[image: Vim (wrap)]

### Vim (nowrap):

[image: Vim (nowrap)]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Vim cannot do this, and I think it would be hard to implement this in a way that isn't inconsistent or confusing to the user. There would need to be an indicator (like with side scrolling) that only the current line is scrolled. Also in Vim, there are several commands (like `j` / `k` and `i_CTRL-Y` / `i_CTRL-E`) that refer to the same column in above / below lines. A partially scrolled view state would make it difficult to use those.

That said, you can sort-of achieve this with a hack: The *foldtext* of folded lines does not scroll horizontally. So if you fold each individual line (other than the current one) via a custom `'foldexpr'`, set the fold text to be the line's text, and automatically close all surrounding folds, you'll get this. However, as you'll lose syntax highlighting and "normal" folding, this is more for demonstration than an actual solution.